# JEE - inject a list of beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I would like to inject a list of beans. I searched in the net, but found not very much. I tried this: https://onlysoftware.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/injecting-lists-cdi-jsf/ but with beans.

View:

```
@UIScoped
public class DemoView extends VerticalLayout {

    @Inject
    private MessageBean messageBean;

    private Button button;

    public DemoView() {
        getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");
        button = new Button("Click me", event -> Notification.show(messageBean.getMessage()));
    }

    public void init() {
        removeAll();
        add(new Label("oh no!"));
        add(button);
    }
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface ViewList {
}
```

InitBean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppInitBean implements Serializable {

    @Produces
    @Named(value = "viewNamedList")
    @ViewList
    public List<DemoView> getViews() {
        return this.generateViews();
    }

    private List<DemoView> generateViews() {
        List<DemoView> views = new ArrayList<DemoView>(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            DemoView emp = new DemoView();
            views.add(emp);
        }
        return views;
    }
}
```

MainClass:

```
@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    @Inject
    @ViewList
    private List<DemoView> viewList;

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        removeAll();
        add(new Label("whatever"));
        for (DemoView demoView : viewList) {
            demoView.init();
            add(demoView);
        }
    }
}
```

The list is produced and will be shown like expected. But if I push the button, I get a NPE -> messageBean is not injected.

So my question is: Is it even possible to inject a list of beans?
I guess if this is possible, it should be also possible to add a element to the list. But one step after an other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost **creating a bean with `new` bypasses CDI and, naturally, injections do not happen**. That is the reason for the NPE.

You can address the problem in two ways: (1) Just as you say, make a list of CDI-managed beans and inject it to whatever asks for it, or (2) make `DemoView` a plain Java object, managed by you, not CDI, and still have CDI produce & inject a list of such things.

#### Solution 2

Solution (2) is simpler, and I would argue more appropriate for some cases. I do not know the exact details of the use case that drives the question, but obviously the `DemoView` is some kind of UI component. When trying to use UI components (like JSF, JavaFX) as CDI beans there is a serious conflict: which framework will create the object? Anyway, change `DemoView` as follows:

```
// No scope annotation!
public class DemoView extends VerticalLayout {
    // No inject!
    private MessageBean messageBean;

    public DemoView(MessageBean messageBean) {
        this.messageBean = messageBean;
    }

    ...
}
```

And the producer becomes:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppInitBean implements Serializable {

    // Inject the collaborators required by DemoView here
    @Inject
    private MessageBean messageBean;

    @Produces
    @Named(value = "viewNamedList")
    @ViewList
    // I would argue you should define a scope here - @UIScoped maybe?
    // This would be the scope of the produced list (and it seems appropriate)
    public List<DemoView> getViews() {
        return this.generateViews();
    }

    private List<DemoView> generateViews() {
        List<DemoView> views = new ArrayList<DemoView>(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            DemoView emp = new DemoView(messageBean); // pass the messageBean
            views.add(emp);
        }
        return views;
    }

    // You may also consider adding a disposer method,
    // if the list of DemoViews needs special cleanup logic.
}
```

If you do not provide a scope for the produced views, the `List` is implicitly `@Dependent`-scoped. Be **very careful** with it, you may need to manually destroy it if injected to a long-lived component (e.g. something `@ApplicationScoped`).

#### Solution 1

If you *really* want solution (1), i.e. producing a list of managed beans you have to take into account that for normal-scoped beans, CDI keeps exactly 1 bean in the active scope and cannot manage more (at least without qualifiers to differentiate the instances). I am *guessing* that `@UIScoped` is a normal scope. If you want to manage the creation of a bean yourself, you also have to (a) make it `@Dependent`-scoped and (b) manage its lifecycle yourself. In order to create many instances of a `@Dependent`-scoped bean, inject an `Instance<DemoView>`.

So, `DemoView` would change to:

```
@Dependent
public class DemoView extends VerticalLayout {
    ...
}
```

And the producer (general concept & untested code, this might have subtle traps):

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppInitBean implements Serializable {

    // Inject the collaborators required by DemoView here
    @Inject
    private Instance<DemoView> demoViewInstance;

    @Produces
    @Named(value = "viewNamedList")
    @ViewList
    @UIScoped // Do give the list a scope!
    public List<DemoView> getViews() {
        return this.generateViews();
    }

    private List<DemoView> generateViews() {
        List<DemoView> views = new ArrayList<DemoView>(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            DemoView emp = demoViewInstance.get(); // creates new instance for @Dependent beans
            views.add(emp);
        }
        return views;
    }

    // Definitely add a disposer method
    void disposeViews(@Disposes @ViewList List<DemoView> views) {
        views.forEach(demoViewInstance::destroy);
    }
}
```

**WARNING: `Instance` and `@Dependent` beans are prone to memory leaks, if not properly used - make sure you use them properly!!!**

Comment: Thanks a lot, solution 1 is what I need.

Comment: [Here](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/cdi-and-instance-3-pitfalls-you-need-to-know/) is an interesting article on the pitfalls of `Instance` you need to know.